# laravel reset password Objeto no localizado!

Tags: php, laravel, email

Me encuentro trabajando sobre laravel en el modulo de restaurar contraseña por medio de correo electrónico.

Feliz mente ya manda correctamente el correo electrónico con el token de vigencia de 60 minutos pero al presionar el botón aun me manda a localhost y no a la dirección de host a la siguiente dirección:

```
http://localhost/password/reset/a2273b24acd61beeef318982942fa7d4be9b0b22a2609cd412d24a74f283d1f
```

Mi pregunta es, donde puedo cambiar la línea o documento que indica el dónde redirige para cachar el token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ejecuta el comando `php artisan cache:clear` y debería de funcionar. Laravel siempre almacena en cache ciertas cosas del proyecto, incluyendo el host, cuando lo mueves de ubicación a otro host, Laravel no sabe que se ha movido, tienes que indicarle que borre el caché para que pueda obtener el host correcto.

Otra solución es que cuando no te es posible correr comandos por alguna razón y necesitas borrar caché, podrías borrar (o renombrar por si algo llega a pasar) el archivo `bootstrap/cache/config.php`.

Antes de borrar la configuración, también asegúrate que la URL de tu proyecto sea la correcta en el archivo `.env`:

Cambia `APP_URL=http://localhost` por `APP_URL=http://tudominio.com`

Comment: hola, puedes darme un ejemplo de como renombrarlo? solo pongo config.php => confi01.php por ejemplo? aun no estoy seguro de algunas cosas que hace auth en laravel y no quiero que falle la aplicacion ya que me costo hacerla funcionar :o

Comment: @clausvargas Así es, puedes ponerle `config2.php` o cualquier otro nombre en realidad y laravel se dará cuenta que no hay de donde jalar caché y por tanto, se verá forzado a crear otro en base a su localización y ubicación actual.

Comment: @clausvargas Obviamente, tendrás que enviar nuevamente el correo después de haber borrado el cache

Comment: @clausvargas Olvidé mencionar algo, edité mi respuesta, y agregué las últimas 3 líneas

Comment: si cheque la parte del .env y medio problemas antes en otra cosa pero si esta bien hoy :) , modifique el archibo config.php y no lo recreo :( y me genero problemas de permisos . y no puedo entrar a consola para generarlo limpiando el cache

Comment: @clausvargas Claro, hay veces que se crean directorios sin los permisos adecuados, pero para esto lamento decirte que si no tienes acceso a consola, tendrás que descargar el proyecto a tu máquina local y correr el siguiente comando: `chmod -R 775 /ruta/a/tu/proyecto` para darle los permisos adecuados.

Comment: alfinal en el documento config enre directamente y modifique la ruta a donde manda el token de reset pasword ...que es basicamente hacer trampa, como minimo e podido hacer la entrega en mi trabajo y me a dado mas tiempo para ver que esta pasando, creo que are eso descargare y ejecutare chmod -R 775  /ruta/a/tu/proyecto para ver los permisos gracias